# It's just a matter of time

Tags: riddle

Clues:

1. People gather because of me, but they're never happy eventually.
2. My name has five letters.
3. My favourite number is four.
4. If you are reading this, you haven't got the honor to meet me yet.
5. The most feared and hated side of two opposites.
6. The title might also help you.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer could be:

> Death

People gather because of me, but they're never happy eventually, because:

> A death is a loss and no one want to lost someone, especially if it is a friend or relative

My name has five letters.

> D E A T H

My favourite number is four.

> In Chinese culture, number 4 means Death

If you are reading this, you haven't got the honor to meet me yet.

> In this moment, I'm not dead yet, it's true

The most feared and hated side of two opposites.

> It can be scary like it can cause anger to lose someone

The title might also help you

> It happens only once

Comment: I just added spoiler blocks to your answer to hide the giveaways from unwitting passers through :)

Answer (score 2):

> This one seems fairly straightforward...the answer, I believe is DEATH. People gathering implying the funeral, five letters, reading this coz one's alive of course, and the justifies the title "it's just a matter of time" too.

That's my answer.